# Angular Material Textarea Auotgrow

Tags: textarea, angular-material2, autogrow

I am using Angular Material textarea. I want to force the autogrow feature to only expand vertically and not horizontally. I tried to set the width, but that is not helping.

```
<md-input-container style="width: 600px">
  <textarea mdInput formControlName="description"
    [(ngModel)]="description" md-textarea-scrollable rows="6" style="width: 650px"></textarea>
</md-input-container>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

"style= resize:vertical"

this only allows the dragging to happen vertically and not horizontally.